# Why do I need to share the certificate with an SP for SSO when the certificate is included in the signed SAML response?

Tags: salesforce, x509certificate, saml, saml-2.0

I am just wondering while implementing SAML SSO with Salesforce I realize that I uploaded the certificate to the SP side (i.e. Salesforce), however I can see when we send a signed SAML response it already includes the certificate.

Why is the certificate shared ahead of time with the SP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about establishing trust between systems. If you don't give SFDC your cert ahead of time, how can they trust the message you are sending is actually from your IDP? Without your cert ahead of time, they can validate that the message is intact but not who actually generated it. When you include your public key in the SAML Response, they can check that it's the same one you shared with them and it's the same one you used to generate the signature.

Comment: They can trust it if it was issued by a trusted CA with the same common name (CN).  An x.509 certificate has the issuing authority, certificate authority, and common name as claims that should be able to verify a certificate's identity.